# abstract get value from different input types

Tags: jquery, select, input

I have html similar to this

```
<input class="rowinput" type="text" id="text_input_1" size="1" value="3">
<input class="rowinput" type="text" id="text_input_2" size="1" value="0">
<select class="rowinput" id="select_input_3">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="0">aaaa</option>
  <option value="1" checked>bbbb</option>
  <option value="2">cccc</option>
  <option value="3">dddd</option>
</select>
```

now I need to use jquery to select all inputs and get their values, and create one string that expresses all the values. I can use this:

```
$('.rowinput').val();
```

this will work perfectly with text inputs, but for select inputs it does not. Because I need it get the text that corresponds to the value, not the value itself. For example, in the code above I need to get "bbbb" and not "1".

then, what I am trying to do is to make a new function, say *textVal()* that gets the value from text inputs and get the text from select inputs:

```
$('.rowinput').textVal();
```

would return : 
3
0
bbbb

I tried to use:

```
input.attr('type');
```

it works fine for text inputs. but for select it returns *undefined*

I don't want to hard code it and treat each input individually because I need to keep my code extensible. 
what is the smart way to do this?

Comment: did u just want selected value or whole thing?

Comment: no, I don't want the value, I need the text that corresponds to the selected value.

Comment: OK see my answer, I guess that will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract all values from class ".rowinput". You could try something like bellow:

```
var concatenatedString = "";

$('.rowinput').each(function(){
var $this = $(this);

if($this.is('input')){
  concatenatedString += $this.val();
} 

if($this.is('select')) {
  concatenatedString += $this.children("option").is("selected").text();
}
});
alert(concatenatedString);
```

​

Comment: if an answer is good enough please select is as the correct answer to improve your rating. otherwise people will stop answering your questions. thank you

Comment: thank you for telling me. I thought I need 15 repetition before I could do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the selected value of `select`. Here is the code

```
<select class="rowinput" id="select_input_3">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="0">aaaa</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">bbbb</option>
  <option value="2">cccc</option>
  <option value="3">dddd</option>
</select>​
```

Jquery, See [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ftdf5/)

```
$(".rowinput option[selected='selected']").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer if you don't like the above:

```
<select>
<option></option>
<option>aaaa</option>
<option>bbbb</option>
<option>cccc</option>
<option>dddd</option>
</select>

<div id='name'></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("select").change(function(){
var text = $(":selected").text();
$('#name').html(text);
});
});
```